# Detener un proceso en puppeteer y luego continuarlo

Tags: nodejs, express, puppeteer

Buscando la forma de hacer un `webscrapping` en una página, me topo con la problemática de un input que funge como captcha.

[image: procuraduria]

La idea, es que una vez renderizada la página, usando `puppeteer`, pueda detener el proceso en el `backend`, devolver la pregunta, que el cliente responda en el lado de la interfaz de la aplicación del `frontend`, y envíe dicha respuesta, para seguir con dicho proceso.

Comment: Si cuando termina de cargar se agrega algo a la web, podrías usar el `waitForSelector(ID_DEL_ELEMENTO_CARGADO)`. Creo recordar que había otro método aun más ... "genérico" que aceptaba un path y tenía más opciones

Comment: @Benito-B Interesante, pero existirá alguna forma de poder detener el proceso de repente.

Comment: Puedes pasarle un timeout, supongo que eso cuenta como detenerlo. `waitForSelector(ID, {timeout: 30})` debería cortar el proceso si tarda más de 30 segundos (creo que era segundos... es posible que sean milis)

Comment: Eso estaba pensando también, Gracias voy a ver que otra cosa se me ocurre probando cada cosa.